# Wifi adapter shuts off

Tags: archlinux, wifi

I am running arch linux on my pi.

My wifi adapter:

```
  Edimax Technology Co., Ltd EW-7811Un 802.11n Wireless Adapter [Realtek RTL8188CUS]
```

On the power front, 12W ipad adapter.

My suspicion was the "power saving feature" of the device. So I created an config file for the module in /etc/modprobe.d/ which disables power saving. It didn't work :(

```
  options 8192cu rtw_power_mgnt=0
```

Comment: I also have this chipset (RTL8188CUS, TP-Link TL-WN725N) and noticed that the Pi would reset upon plugging in this adapter. Using the [adapter included by RS Components](http://raspberrypi.rsdelivers.com/product/rs/hnp06-microusb/micro-usb-euro-power-supply-for-raspberry-pi/7263053.aspx).

Comment: It resets? 
The adapter I have works for a couple of mins to a few hours. Then the led is just stable (Its blinks when there is some activity) . I can't ssh to the machine or anything. I am thinking of adding a cron job so that it pings the router every few mins or so.

Comment: Yes, it reboots (due to the power flux?). What would the cron be good for? I suggest you to setup syslog and have a look in /var/log/. You might also be able to use `journalctl -ab` if the Pi has not reset (thereby losing logs)

Comment: The device I use is not connected to a display. So I am assuming that the pi is running and the wifi-adapter is not. 
I was under the impression that the adapter just shuts off due to inactivity. Hence the cron job.

Comment: You can also SSH over Ethernet? Or do you have Model A? If PM is disabled, then the adapter will not go to sleep.

Comment: It seems to be working for the last few hours mate. A cron job to ping my router for every 1 min seems to do the trick for now

Comment: Have you solved this issue yet? If so, could you please create a self-answer and mark it as such. We are trying to get the Q:A ratio up and that would help us a ton. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

To disable power saving mode, you have to add "wireless-power off" in your "interfaces" file

1/ Type

```
sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces
```

2/ Add at the end of file

```
wireless-power off
```

3/ Reboot by typing :

```
sudo reboot
```