# WiFi Edimax EW-7811UN down after Router Reboot

Tags: wifi, connection

I'm running the RaspberryPi as a Server that is connected to the network over WiFi using the Edimax EW-7811UN Dongle. I configured the dongle according to the [documentation](http://rtl8192cu.googlecode.com/hg-history/bdd3a2265bdd6a92f24cef3d52fa594b2844c9c1/document/HowTo_enable_the_power_saving_functionality.pdf), like

opening configfile

```
sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/8192cu.conf
```

pasting

```
options 8192cu rtw_power_mgnt=0 rtw_enusbss=0
```

to disable all sorts of powersaving. But still: As soon as the WiFi router disables the WiFi connection the Dongle does not wake up any more. The connection can not be re-established.

If've already found a work-around (from the [Raspberry Pi forums](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=61665)), to run this script as cronjob

```
#!/bin/bash
# check if a wlan0 if exists
if echo `/sbin/ifconfig` | grep -q $1; then
#check if there is IP Address
  if echo `/sbin/ifconfig $1` | grep -q "inet Adresse"; then
    exit 0
  fi
  /sbin/modprobe -r 8192cu
fi
/sbin/modprobe 8192cu
exit 0
```

But that doesn't smell like the clean solution I'm looking for. Does anybody else experience this issue and has a simpler solution?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am running the same wifi adapter on a RPi A+ running updated raspbian wheezy and do not experience those outages:

```
bob@raspi09:~% lsb_release -d
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 7.8 (wheezy)
bob@raspi09:~% uname -a
Linux raspi09 4.1.6+ #810 PREEMPT Tue Aug 18 15:19:58 BST 2015 armv6l GNU/Linux
```

Here's my current `/etc/modprobe.d/8192cu.conf`:

```
# Disable power management
options 8192cu rtw_power_mgnt=0 rtw_enusbss=0 rtw_ips_mode=1
```

I did have a very similar problem on an older Model B with the same adapter, but recent updates seem to have cleared up the problem. I had previously tried adding `wireless-power off` to `/etc/networking/interfaces` as discussed in [this thread](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/8748/wifi-adapter-shuts-off?rq=1) but encountered error messages, so abandoned that approach.

Is your RPi firmware up to date? (`sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get upgrade`)

Also -- Just to be certain -- Is there any chance the RPi is connecting to another AP/router when your primary drops off? Can you get onto it to check `ifconfig`?

Comment: you might want to change that last question into a conditional statement like "It might be that your RPI firmware is not up to date, here is how you update the firmware ..... "

Comment: My RPi is up to date (`Linux rpi 4.1.6+ #810 PREEMPT Tue Aug 18 15:19:58 BST 2015 armv6l`), but I was missing the line `rtw_ips_mode=1`. I'll watch what happens next few days and mark your answer as correct when the connection is stable :) Thanks ! PS: RPi doesn't connect to another AP or router since ethernet is disconnected and only one WiFi password is given